# Is it possible to call MathGL functions from .NET?

Tags: .net, python, mathgl

As in the subject - if I would like to create a publication ready graph from .NET, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up calling the Matlab runtime functions. MatPlotLib also works well, but would require IronPython for interop between .NET and Python.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible. You just need to use C functions of MathGL from .NET.